# How do you write Vlookup code to search a different workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I cannot figure out how to enter vlookup code into my existing code (below) that looks to another workbook and updates my master workbook.  The Vlookup formula would look like this:

**=VLOOKUP(B2,'[Loading Summary.xlsx]SHIPPING'!$A:$K,11,FALSE** .

I've also provided a couple screen shots.  Both workbooks Master & Raw data have multiple, corresponding tabs. The tricky part is; I can't just do a copy and paste every time the raw data updates.  My team makes notes on the Master Schedule and doesn't want their notes or fields to change, they just want the hours column to change.

[Master Schedule - Workbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etAMM.jpg)
[Raw Data - Workbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDmRc.jpg)

[Error after trying Williams code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDkGk.jpg)

```vb
    Sub Import_Awea_LP2516()

       'Prevents Clipboard Pop-up from appearing.
       Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        
       'Prevents screen flicker and makes the macro run faster.
       Application.ScreenUpdating = False
       
       'Ensures the Loading Summary is open
       Workbooks.Open Filename:=Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Dropbox (Napoleon Machine)\Operations Management\#MASTER SCHEDULE\Shop Schedule V4\Loading Summary.xlsx"

       'Copies new line items from loading summary and pastes them at the bottom of the master schedule (per machine)
       Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = Workbooks("Shop Schedule - Master V4.xlsm").Worksheets("Awea-LP2516")
       Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = Workbooks("Loading Summary.xlsx").Worksheets("LP2516")
       Dim criteria As String
       Dim found As Range
       Dim i As Long

       For i = 2 To 500
       criteria = ws1.Cells(i, 2).Value
       On Error Resume Next
       Set found = ws2.Range("A:A").Find(What:=criteria, LookAt:=xlWhole)
       On Error GoTo 0

       If found Is Nothing Then
       ws1.Cells(i, 2).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 22
       End If
        Next i

       Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
       Dim wsDest As Worksheet
       Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
       Dim lDestLastRow As Long


       Set wsCopy = Workbooks("Loading Summary.xlsx").Worksheets("LP2516")
       Set wsDest = Workbooks("Shop Schedule - Master V4.xlsm").Worksheets("Awea-LP2516")
        

       lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        
       lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(2).Row

       wsCopy.Range("A2:O" & lCopyLastRow).Copy _
       wsDest.Range("B" & lDestLastRow)
        
       Windows("Shop Schedule - Master V4.xlsm").Activate
        
       Dim rCell As Range
       Dim rRange As Range
       Dim lCount As Long

       Set rRange = Range("B2", Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
       lCount = rRange.Rows.Count

       For lCount = lCount To 1 Step -1
         With rRange.Cells(lCount, 1)
            If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rRange, .Value) > 1 Then
                .EntireRow.Delete
             End If
         End With
       Next lCount
      
      Windows("Shop Schedule - Master V4.xlsm").Activate
      Rows(2).EntireRow.Delete
      Range("A2").Select
     
      Call Master_Sheet_Cleanup
          
      Workbooks("Loading Summary.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=False
          
      'Turns display alerts back on
      Application.DisplayAlerts = True
      Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    End Sub
```

Comment: FYI you don't need to wrap `Find()` in `On Error Resume Next` - it will not raise an error if there's no match.

Comment: Thank you Tim, also how did you get the code to format properly.  I've asked a few questions on here and when I paste code it never uses VBA color formatting.

Comment: Don't use the "snippet" button - begin your code block with three backticks followed by `lang-vb` and close out the code with 3 backticks

Comment: `Dim res: res = Application.Vlookup(workSheetHere.Range("B2").Value, Workbooks("Loading Summary.xlsx").Worksheets("Shipping").Range("A:K"),11, False)` Then use `If IsError(res)` to check if a match was found before proceeding.

Comment: Tim, thank you for the heads up on the backticks and posting.  I read the App.Vlookup you suggested.  Warning, you will have to break out the Crayola crayons for me lolol.  I'm working on VBA code I didn't create, I'm borderline brainless when it comes to VBA code.  Should I be placing the code you provided within the procedure?  I imagine so as it's particular to the sheets I'm jumping between.  However, I don't know where to place the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my best guess at what you want to do

```vb
Sub Import_Awea_LP2516()

    Dim wbSSM As Workbook, wbLS As Workbook, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim criteria As String
    Dim found As Range
    Dim wsCopy As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim rRange As Range
    Dim res
 
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Set wbSSM = Workbooks("Shop Schedule - Master V4.xlsm") 'ThisWorkbook?
    Set wsDest = wbSSM.Worksheets("Awea-LP2516")
    
    On Error Resume Next 'in case workbook is not open
    Set wbLS = Workbooks("Loading Summary.xlsx")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If wbLS Is Nothing Then
        Set wbLS = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\" & _
                 "Dropbox (Napoleon Machine)\Operations Management\#MASTER SCHEDULE\" & _
                 "Shop Schedule V4\Loading Summary.xlsx")
    End If
    Set wsCopy = wbLS.Worksheets("LP2516")
    
    'flag lines in wsDest with no ColA match on wsCopy
    For i = 2 To 500
        With wsDest.Cells(i, 2)
            'Match is faster than Find
            If IsError(Application.Match(.Value, wsCopy.Range("A:A"), 0)) Then
                .EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 22
            End If
        End With
    Next i
    
    wsCopy.Range("A2:O" & wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Copy _
           wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(2)
    
    Set rRange = wsDest.Range("B2", wsDest.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    For i = rRange.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        With rRange.Cells(i, 1)
            If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rRange, .Value) > 1 Then
                .EntireRow.Delete 'duplicate:remove
            Else
                'not removing this row - perform lookup for hours
                res = Application.VLookup(.Value, wbLS.Sheets("shipping").Range("A:K"), 11, False)
                If Not IsError(res) Then .EntireRow.Cells(11).Value = res
                'not clear what should happen if vlookup fails here?
            End If
        End With
    Next i
    
    wbLS.Close SaveChanges:=False
      
    wsDest.Rows(2).EntireRow.Delete
    wbSSM.Activate
    wsDest.Select
    wsDest.Range("A2").Select
    
    Call Master_Sheet_Cleanup
        
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Tim, thanks so much for helping me.  Your proposed code is precisely what I'm looking for.  I did have to edit the sheet name for "res = "  from "shipping" to "LP2516"  I also changed the range on that as I forgot to account for a hidden column.  I'm getting an error that states Invalid number of arguments.  Check out my attached screenshot.

Comment: Added screenshot to original post.

Comment: Typo >> `res = Application.VLookup(...`